# How can I load any VSCode extension for any specific filetype?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use vscode-vim extension for my usual editing purpose. But I don't want this extension to  be loaded when I'm using Jupyter Notebook inside VSCode. Is there any way I can tell VSCode to load this extension only when I'm using normal files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no. There are two issues in VSCodeVim related to this issue, but neither has resulted in introducing the feature you are looking for (yet).

[Setting to enable Vim Editor only for certain filetypes #6151](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6151)

[Disable vim *only* for jupyter notebook editors #6950](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6950) .